# java Vulnerability Upgraded common collection 3.2 to 3.2.2 jar in Pom.xml How to include only Common collection 3.2.2 in compiled war or jar files?

Tags: maven

upgraded commons collection jar from 3.2 version to 3.2.2 after that when i make clean build in war lib folder i found both 3.2 and 3.2.2 common collection jars.

commented commons-collection 3.2 dependency in Pom.xml

How can i include only commons collection 3.2.2 in latest builds?

Comment: With Maven, you can only have only version of a dependency (if they share the same groupId and artifactId). Are you sure you have two versions of commons collections with same groupId and same artifactId?

Comment: Why do you copy my question?

Comment: sorry its typo mistake. common collection jars  shares same groupid and artifactid. Thanks ..

Comment: Then your clean probably did not work properly. Try "clean install" and look for error messages.